# Disappearing controls in modal dialogs when I press the left Alt key

Tags: delphi, controls, delphi-7

I use the XPMan unit in a Delphi 7 project to make the controls round shaped. When I open a modal dialog and press the left Alt key (change the keyboard layout to another language by Alt-Shift), some controls (most likely buttons) disappear and just apperar again when I move the cursor over them. When I remove the XPMan, the error cease. Is there any other solution to it then removing XPMan? (This is the same with the Win10 metafile)

Comment: Try the latest version of Delphi

Comment: Changing to a newer version is not a trivial task because of the unicode conversion.

Comment: Start by checking whether or not that makes a difference. Track down which version changed behaviour. Then see what changed in the source.

Comment: You're asking why a decade-old version of Delphi doesn't work properly in a modern OS. The change to Unicode happened in Delphi 2009, which was released six years ago. You've had that long to work on that *not a trivial task*. XPMan was a temporary solution (based on the outstanding work of a third-party) to provide theme support to the VCL, and the fact it doesn't work properly now shouldn't be unexpected.

Comment: Dump "XPMan unit" and include a manifest file by `{$I}`. And also state on which target OS you're experiencing this problem. By "a modal dialog" do you mean a custom form or something like `MessageBoxA()`?

Comment: The problem is not in XPMan, it is a theme bug in StdCtrls, and patching that is the best way to solve it in Delphi 7 with theme support of any kind.

Comment: The answer below works ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure SendKey_ALT;
begin
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, 0), 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;
```

Call the above procedure from your FormCreate() method. This will solve your problem.